# How to check if the multidimensional array contains certain key and value pair on all "levels"?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multi-dimensional array:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        array(
            'page_id'    => '75',
            'book_color' => 'red',
            'book_name'  => 'Bible - patch nr. 593',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        array(
            array(
                'page_id'    => '85',
                'book_color' => 'blue',
                'book_name'  => 'Bible',
            ),
            array(
                'page_id'    => '84',
                'book_color' => 'black',
                'book_name'  => 'Bible - extended version',
            ),
            array(
                'page_id'    => '83',
                'book_color' => 'green',
                'book_name'  => 'Bible - for children and Americans',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'page_id'    => '68',
            'book_color' => 'green',
            'book_name'  => 'Bible - Quran mashup',
        ),

    ),
    array(
        'page_id'    => '96',
        'book_color' => 'yellow',
        'book_name'  => 'Bible - patch nr. 594',
    ),
);
```

And I need to check if this array contains this key => value pair:

`'book_name'  => 'Bible'`

So, as you can see, it can by in the first subarray or the second or even inside of more nested arrays.

How to make a check that can return true or false depending if there is found, no matter on what level, this keyand value pair.

Comment: And what to do if it doesn't have

Comment: @Uchiha return false or echo "God not found"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_walk_recursive` over here like as

```
$book_name = [];

array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k)use(&$book_name) {
    if ($k == 'book_name') {
        $book_name[$v] = (strpos($v,"Bible") !== false) ? "Found" : "God not found";
    }
});
print_r($book_name);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/448928)

Comment: Wow, I will check this solution. interesting.